# How to do "NumPad ." on a mac

Tags: osx, actions

I'm trying to focus on a tiny object and the emulator as far I see doesn't do "NumPad ." actions on a Mac. Also the + and - don't zoom me into focusing on the object. I'm either too far away or I zoom in and get too close and can't see the object. What is the quick key for "NumPad ." or a drop down menu option for it if someone doesn't have a number-pad and the Blender emulator doesn't emulate number-pad actions that don't use a number? What are the alternative actions for number-pad (and something that isn't a number)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not using mac, but I think I can help you.

First go to Edit->Preferences->Keymap.

And then select Key-Binding:
[image]

Now you can search for the shortcut that you want (in this case you will search for ".") and change it to whatever you want.
I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you. I hope one day they get rid of the numberpad actions that don't use numbers. Most computers (even pcs) don't have a numberpad. It's a lot of work to remember what the quick keys are for. Plus most of them just end up being "A" for a quick key in the same group of quick keys. So I'll try it again and see what happens.

Comment: If the answer worked please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3):

In *Edit > Preferences > Input > Keyboard*, there is an option to ***Emulate Numpad***, which will allow you to use the numbers on your keyboard as numpad.

[image]

Comment: See [How to write good answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Kynux Thanks for the suggestion. Though what I said and was asking is that the emulator only emulates numberpad numbers, not any other numberpad actions that aren't number like the action "Numerpad Decimalpoint" it looks like "Numberpad ." which doesn't work with the emulator. I was wondering if there are dropdown menu selections to do these non number numberpad actions? Because a numberpad has other things on it besides numbers whic are also numberpad quick keys in Blender.

Comment: @KelliConan you could assign another hotkey for numpad 0 it is possible but i dont know how to do it myself